# How can I get data twice from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to get data after the request in the service and in the component. I found a way, only through the direct extraction of the variable from service through the `subscription.add method.`

**Service Code:**

```
itemList: any[];
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
getData(){
  return this.http.get('items.json').subscribe(data => {
    this.itemList = data['itemList'];
  });
}
```

**Component Code:**

```
items: any[];
constructor(private dataService :DataService) { }
ngOnInit() {
}
getItems() {
  this.dataService.getData().add(data => { 
    this.items = this.dataService.itemList;
});
}
```

Is there a way to do this through a re-subscription or something similar
,since if you try to extract the data in the add block it goes out indefined

```
add(data => { 
  this.items = data['itemList'];
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: what is add block? your own function?

Comment: you should be either pushing it to `localStorage` or use some redux state management technique

Comment: @SurajRao No, add is subscription function

Comment: what do you mean by after the request.. y not subscribe in the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `do` in `DataService` instead `subscribe`. And subscribe in controller

```
...
// Service
getData(){
  return this.http.get('items.json').do(data => {
    this.itemList = data['itemList'];
  });
}

...
// Component
getItems() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => { 
    this.items = this.dataService.itemList;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, to simply pass the request first

```
getData(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('items.json);
}
```

and in the component call the service upon processing

```
getItems() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(response => { 
    <do whatever you have to do with response items>
    this.dataService.setItemList(response);
});
```

at the dataService:

```
public setItemList(items: any){
   this.itemList = data['itemList']; // or anything you need to do with the original data
}
```